# Sublime Text Double Click highlighting modification

Tags: sass, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Sublime Text does not register a sass variable ($variable) as a single item when highlighting, so when I double click on the name, it highlights the word, but does not include the $-symbol in the highlighting. Visual Studio, on the other hand, selects the $-symbol along with the variable name when double clicking on a variable to select it.

I write sass all day long, and it could make my life drastically easier if I could modify this small behavior. Is there a way to change this? I am sure it would be possible with a plugin, but I don't know if one exists or how to find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a setting named `word_separators` which provides a list of characters that are assumed to not be part of a word for the purposes of things like double click selection, navigating by words, and so on.

The default for that particular setting is set to the following, which includes the `$` character that is causing you woes:

```
// Characters that are considered to separate words
"word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?",
```

You can modify this setting to not include the `$` character so that it's treated as a part of the identifier, which should do what you want.

In order to ensure that you don't experience any other knock-on effects of this, you may want to set the setting in the preferences specific to the Sass syntax.

To do that, you can select `Preferences > Settings - Syntax Specific` while you have a Sass file open and focused, and then copy the default setting into those settings and remove the `$` character.

Comment: Amazing. I wasn't really expecting an answer, much less one that is so quick, easy, and customizeable.

Comment: copy the default setting into those settings and remove the $ character - make this bold please